# Define Callback in interface Typescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I want to implement an interface with a list of functions and attributes, few functions required to work on callback mode. For example

```
interface Writer{
     readData : (fileLocation: string) => void;
     generatData: (fileLocation: string) => void;
}
```

I would like to execute generateData function and notify after job is done. For example

```
const WriterInstance:Writer ={
   generateData("C:/workspace" , ()=>{
       console.log("work is done");
   });
   readData("C:/workspace/file1.text" , ()=>{
       console.log("work is done");
   })
}
```

I am totally misunderstanding the syntax & invocation of callbacks in the interface. If anyone explains with example then it will be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Define writer interface
interface Writer{
     readData : (fileLocation: string, callback: () => void) => void;
     generateData: (fileLocation: string, callback: () => void) => void;
}

// Create writer
const writerInstance: Writer = {
   generateData: (fileLocation: string, callback: () => void) => {
    // generate data
    callback();
},
   readData: (fileLocation: string, callback: () => void) => {
    //read data
    callback();
}
}

// Call writer methods
writerInstance.generateData("C:/workspace", ()=>{
     console.log("work is done");
 });

writerInstance.readData("C:/workspace/file1.text" , ()=>{
     console.log("work is done");
 });
```

Answer (score 2):

Just imagine that the callback function is a normal parameter. Then, define `WriterInstance` as a normal object - Just define it's properties

```
interface Writer{
  readData : (fileLocation: string, callback: () => void) => void;
  generateData: (fileLocation: string, callback: (error: Error, data?: any) => void) => void;
}

const WriterInstance: Writer = {
  readData: (fileLocation: string, callback: () => void) => {
    // dome something with fileLocation
    callback();
  },

  generateData: (fileLocation: string, callback: (error: Error, data?: any) => void) => {
    // dome something with fileLocation
    callback(null, true);
  }
}

// usage of WriterInstance
WriterInstance.generateData('C:/workspace/file1.text', (error, data) => {
  if (error) {
    console.log('work is not done');
    return console.log(error);
  }
  console.log('work is done');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In your interface, you want to represent a function with two parameters, the first one is a string and the second one is a function so you can write it like that:

```
interface Writer{
     readData : (fileLocation: string, callback: ()=>void) => void;
     generateData: (fileLocation: string, callback: ()=>void) => void;
}
```